# Push notification for enterprise windows store app

Tags: push-notification, windows-store-apps

Is there any way to push notifications to a windows store app that isn't deployed on the store ? My application is an enterprise one, deployed by side loading.

Thank you,

Mathieu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post about deploying Enterprise Apps is mentioning the following about push notifications without deploying the app to the Windows Store:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657971.aspx

*Note  In order to use some features, such as Windows Push Notification Services (WNS), you’ll need to use a Windows Store developer account to reserve a name for your app and then associate your package with the the package identity (package name and publisher name) assigned to your app by the Windows Store. You will need to sign the app with a certificate that matches the publisher name assigned by the Windows Store and which is trusted on your PCs. While app names are released after one year if the app is not published in the Windows Store, the app’s package identity will remain associated with your app, and you can continue to use these features in your app even if you never publish it in the Store.*

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to use a certificate from a public authority? (so we won't need to install the store cert on the client machines)