# Alternative to push notifications on Windows 8

Tags: windows-runtime, push-notification, windows-store-apps

Im working on a windows 8.1 project for a client, the app wont be on store.
I was asked to implement push notifications but from what i've read we need to register app on store to enable that funcionality.

Is there any other alternativo to push notifications or a way of getting them without having the app on store?

Comment: You can submit your app to the store but not publish it.  That should allow you to use push notifications

Comment: Ah OK, that might work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push notification for enterprise windows store app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833421/push-notification-for-enterprise-windows-store-app)

Comment: Is there a way i can send test notifications with the info i have on store ( SID and whatnots) ?