# Enable Push Notifications for Enterprise Application

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, mpns, wns, windows-10-mobile

I'm new to Windows Phone 8.1 development.

I have developed a Windows app for Windows Phone 8.1 using Visual Studio 2013 and enabled push notifications into it using WNS service, but WNS is only available for Windows Store apps not for enterprise apps (using Intune Signed certificate).

How can I enable Push Notification for Enterprise app?

Answer (score 0):

[Source :[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833421/push-notification-for-enterprise-windows-store-app]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833421/push-notification-for-enterprise-windows-store-app)
This post about deploying Enterprise Apps is mentioning the following about push notifications without deploying the app to the Windows Store: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj657971.aspx

Note In order to use some features, such as Windows Push Notification Services (WNS), you’ll need to use a Windows Store developer account to reserve a name for your app and then associate your package with the the package identity (package name and publisher name) assigned to your app by the Windows Store. You will need to sign the app with a certificate that matches the publisher name assigned by the Windows Store and which is trusted on your PCs. While app names are released after one year if the app is not published in the Windows Store, the app’s package identity will remain associated with your app, and you can continue to use these features in your app even if you never publish it in the Store.

Comment: I went through the mentioned link previously also but the content of that website has been moved and there is a link "This content can be found here: Publish Windows apps." i went there also but didn't find any useful information.
If you have any update regarding the same please share here.

Comment: Connect with your enterprise account on the site developper.microsoft.com. Go the the dashboard section. here in the left, you'll see your apps. You have to create an app. Then you'll have the ability to navigate to this app. Go on the App identity section under App management. Here, there is the package identity name and publisher ID that you have to set in your manifest.xml inside your app. It's mandatory in order to make the WNS works.