# Are push notifications (WNS) supported for LOB apps in UWP?

Tags: windows-phone, uwp

I have googled a lot but I am not getting whether Push Notifications(WNS) are supported for UWP LOB apps. For windows, phone 8.1 push notifications were only supported for store apps, not for LOB. ([source](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2014/WIN-B352))

So I want to know whether UWP LOB apps supports Push Notification(WNS).

If yes then can you please provide the links from where I can follow the steps.

Comment: can you provide the link where it saiys WP 8.1 LOB apps don't support WNS? Are you maybe confusing LOB (line of business) applications for something else?

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2014/WIN-B352

Comment: hi @AlexDrenea you can check out video on this link where they say LOB  Apps don't support wns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push notification for enterprise windows store app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833421/push-notification-for-enterprise-windows-store-app)